# Add Azure AD Group like normal SharePoint Group to SharePoint Sites/Lists using HTTP request

Tags: azure, permissions, azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I can add normal SharePoint Group to SharePoint using below HTTP request

```
https://imfdevdm.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Sample Library')/items(1)/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid=12, roledefid=1073741827)
```

Similarly is there a method to add an Azure AD Group??

There is no initial principal Id for a AAD Group initially. If an AAD group is already added manually to SharePoint, then for that Group, a principal ID is generated. Else, we can't find a principal Id for the AAD Group.

If a principal Id was present, the same above HTTP request was enough to add role assignments.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**Updated:**

I think this is not possible. The usual procedure is to add AAD Group to a SharePoint Group and then add it to SharePoint Sites/Lists

Answer (score 0):

You can do this either through the Azure Portal or the O365 portal. I don't think it's possible to do this via HTTP requests and you're right that the recommended procedure is to create the Group in Azure AD and then assign it to SharePoint. You can also do this through Powershell but unless your creating a ton at once the portal is the easiest way.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/sharepoint-on-premises-tutorial